# why php cannot show variable in string template under some circumstances?

Tags: php

Thanks for your time in advance. I am a newbie in php and encountered a strange problem, at least for me it is strange. It is about showing variable in string template. Please see the code below:

```
public function welcome() {
    $data="everyone";
    $b = $this->returnTemplate();
    $a = "<div>dear $data</div>";
}
public function returnTemplate()
{
    return "<div>dear $data</div>";
}
```

I just thought both $a and $b should be the same value `<div>dear everyone</div>` but in fact only $a is while $b is `<div>dear </div>`.
That really puzzled me and I wonder why? Could someone please to explain it to me?

Thanks in advance and any feedback is welcome!

Comment: It's called [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), and it's fully documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering 'variable scope'. As you have defined the variable $data in the welcome() function, it will not be available anywhere outside of that function. To overcome this, either move it out of the function OR pass it as a parameter to the returnTemplate function.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: many thanks, that seems a stupid question, I know how to do now

Answer (score 0):

```
public function welcome() {
 $data="everyone";
 $b = $this->returnTemplate($data);
 $a = "<div>dear $data</div>";
}
public function returnTemplate($data)
{
  return "<div>dear $data</div>";
}
```

this works.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: great, I know the reason now, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned, you are trying to breach the *variable scope*. In other words you are trying to use a *local variable* out of its scope (the function you have initially declared/defined in). 
There are two ways to achieve what you are trying:

1) Pass the variable as a parameter to the function and then use the returned value, something like this:

```
public function welcome() {
 $data="everyone";
 $b = $this->returnTemplate($data);
 $a = "<div>dear $data</div>";
}
public function returnTemplate($data)
{
  return "<div>dear $data</div>";
}
```

2) Declare the variable as *GLOBAL* on the top/start. So it will have a scope out of that *particular* function and achieve exactly what you are trying to.

Comment: thanks a lot, I know how to do now~